# Why is this If statement evaluating to true when it is clearly false?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4 and having a really hard time understanding why the following IF statement returns true:

[image]

As you can see from the popup, the value of "shuffleMode" is clearly 2,
yet the IF statement proceeds as though the value == 1.

I have tried this with the Enum version:

```
if (myMP.shuffleMode == .off) {
   //code for true
}
```

and get the same results.

Can anyone tell me why this happening, and more importantly how to fix it?

Comment: Can you show the `enum`?

Comment: My guess would be that the debugger shows the wrong value. Sadly this happens under some circumstances. Try logging the value to the console. As a side note - you really shouldn't use the rawValue like this.

Comment: you need to add the enum to the code so we can get a clearer understanding of where the problem might possibly arise from

Comment: I've had problems like this when Xcode 10 came out, and they all went away when I switched to the legacy build system, so maybe give that a try.

Comment: Sometimes you just don't get enough information from the debugger and you have to resort to `print` statements. Try adding `print("shuffleMode: \(myMP.shuffleMode.rawValue)")` as the first statement in the `setShuffleButImage` method. Also add print statements inside each branch of the `if` statement. What output do you get? Paste the modified source code and the output into your question.

Comment: @LanceSamaria The Enum is specified here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicshufflemode but the IF statement does not evaluate properly even though the Enum values show correctly.

Comment: Regardless of what I have tried, I can't get it to work so I've instead decided to save the ShuffleMode value to defaults then read and use it instead. So I've gotten it working fine, just not as expected.

Comment: I just looked at the link you sent. .off had a value of 1. Did you try using a switch statement on myP.shufflemode and running the check on default, off, songs, and album instead of using the rawValue?

Comment: @LanceSamaria Yes, I've tried all of that...that's why I ended up posting here because nothing I've tried has worked. Since I've gotten it working I'm just going to move on - there's plenty of other weirdness with the MusicPlayer that I'm facing...thanks.

Comment: Np, god luck! You should post whatever you used to get it working so the next person who has this problem will be able to use your answer. Cheers!

Comment: I would post the code but it's pretty specific to my app. Generally speaking, I simply maintain the 'desired' shufflemode (songs, off, etc) in a var. The var value is also stored/retrieved as a User default. I then simply use that value as needed.